# Sublime Text 2 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vim, sublimetext2

I'm testing sublime text 2 and I'm impressed with some features but I can't find Vim ":R" option that switch from model to controller, from controller action to the view and so on.

Let me know if there is option for this in sublime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SublimeText2RailsRelatedFiles](https://github.com/luqman/SublimeText2RailsRelatedFiles) is the closest ST2 plugin to mimic rails.vim's `gf` behavior.

An excerpt from the documentation:

> Here I've pressed the shortcut key when looking at the "page.rb" file under models:
>
> [image: example of navigation]